# Different behaviour of the same code and same seed on different machines

Tags: haskell, random, random-seed

I'm testing my code with *pseudo-random* number generator with the same seed on my PC (Ubuntu) and on remote server (FreeBSD) and these are the results.

My PC (ghci 8.8.4):

```
> Prelude> import System.Random
> Prelude System.Random> let (elemIdx, newGen) = randomR (0, 199) (mkStdGen 40)
> Prelude System.Random> elemIdx
94
```

Server (ghci 7.6.3):

```
> Prelude> import System.Random
> Prelude System.Random> let (elemIdx, newGen) = randomR (0, 199) (mkStdGen 40)
> Prelude System.Random> elemIdx
43
```

Strangely enough I'm getting different results (94 my PC, 43 server) with same seed. What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: It uses an `Int` iirc, and the "width" of an `Int` can differ based on the platform (32-bit vs 64-bit).

Comment: What versions of the random library? 1.2 changed the prng algorithm entirely.

Comment: The generator is an instance of  the `Show` class, so you can print its contents on both your platforms, before and after extracting the first random number.